# How to get drawable name of view

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have two types of buttons and I've set a drawable background for each button.
The names of the drawable backgrounds are `backgroundblack.xml` and `backgroundwhite.xml`.

When I click on a button how can I know which background is used as drawable background for the clicked button.

Some thing like this:

```
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myButton.getBackground().getBackgroundName();
            }
        });
```

I suppose that this line would give me `backgroundblack` or `backgroundwhite`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Will Work

myView.getBackgroundDrawable();

Comment: Accualy I am using View Not Button ... it is not working with view ... is there any thing similar to this work fine with View ?

Comment: you mentioned in your question that you are using button,I have edited my answer for view

Comment: Yes i am using button but   i sent it in a function as View and when i try to write view.getCompoundDrawables()[0] it is not accepted